# ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to change the user type. Doing through STI.

Clicking the link passes the parameter :type.

My models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
class Admin < User
class Seller < User
class Guest < User
```

Views

```
tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      tr 
        td = user.email
        td = user.type
        td = link_to "admin", edit_user_path(user, type: 'Admin')
        td = link_to "guest", edit_user_path(user, type: 'Guest')
        td = link_to "seller", edit_user_path(user, type: 'Seller')
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users 
  resources :admins, controller: :users, :type => "Admin"
  resources :guests, controller: :users, :type => "Guest"
  resources :sellers, controller: :users, :type => "Seller"
```

Error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: user

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"56bC4iWSsYd+VrN7RV0NCMj4YD+fIMQKb8uKKC9dUkMtOORAilwPlk3oAgT2L8j5qMsH4tNdzy6zbdL5nVVi7Q==", "type"=>"Admin", "id"=>"3"}
```

controller

```
  def update
    if current_admin
      if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to users_path
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:type)
  end
```

Why this error? action expects that one parameter :the user, but it is not?

Comment: `params.require(:user)` means that you should have a key named user in your parameters.

Comment: please paste your update action.

Comment: in body of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` ensures that a parameter is present. If it's present, returns the parameter at the given key, otherwise raises an `ActionController::ParameterMissing error`.

**You are requiring `user` parameter but it's missing from the params.**

To get this you have many ways.

**Method 1:**

Removing require should do the trick.

**`params.permit(:type)`**

**Method2:**

Add a `user[]` as a name to the input in the edit form.

**Will elaborate the method 1 if you add the edit form.**

**Method3:**

The other solution is to add the user key to the parameters.

```
def update
    if current_admin
        params.user = {
            "type": params.type,
            "id": params.id
        }
      if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to users_path
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:type)
  end
```

[reference to api documentaiton](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

Comment: error: ```undefined method `type' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0xafadde14>```

Comment: seems you got an issue with the 1st method, try the 3rd method once, I will update the correct syntax of 1st method in the mean time.

Comment: use `params.permit!` to permit all the parameters